# can't delete subscriber aweber api php wrapper

Tags: api, aweber

As expected on documentation for delete subscriber but its not working

```
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');

$consumerKey    = '***'; # put your credentials here
$consumerSecret = '***'; # put your credentials here
$accessKey      = '***'; # put your credentials here
$accessSecret   = '***'; # put your credentials here
$account_id     = '***'; # put the Account ID here
$list_id        = '***'; # put the List ID here

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

try {
    $account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);
    $listURL = "/accounts/{$account_id}/lists/{$list_id}";
    $list = $account->loadFromUrl($listURL);

    # subscriber to delete
    $params = array(
        'email' => 'johndoe@example.com'
    );
    $subscribers = $list->subscribers;
    $new_subscriber = $subscribers->delete($params);

    # success!
    print "Subscriber was deleted!";

} catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) {
    print "<h3>AWeberAPIException:</h3>";
    print " <li> Type: $exc->type              <br>";
    print " <li> Msg : $exc->message           <br>";
    print " <li> Docs: $exc->documentation_url <br>";
    print "<hr>";
    exit(1);
}
```

My reference https://labs.aweber.com/snippets/subscribers#del

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. Its working for me

```
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');

$consumerKey = '###';
$consumerSecret = '###';
$accessKey = '###';
$accessSecret = '###';
$account_id = '###';
$list_id = '###';

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

try {
    $account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);
    $listURL = "/accounts/{$account_id}/lists/{$list_id}";
    $list = $account->loadFromUrl($listURL);

    $params = array(
        'email' => 'info@examples.com'
    );

    $subscribers = $list->subscribers;
    $found_subscribers = $subscribers->find($params);

    foreach ($found_subscribers as $subscriber) {
        $subscriber->delete();
    }

    print "Subscriber was deleted!";

} catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) {

    print "AWeberAPIException:";
    print "Type: $exc->type";
    print "Msg : $exc->message";
    print "Docs: $exc->documentation_url";
    exit(1);
}
```